# Can I drive a USB webcam with my android touchpad?

Tags: usb, touchscreen, usb-peripherals

I have I have an Android touchpad and a usb webcam... Can I use the pad to control the webcam?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think directly. There are, however, several apps in the market that seem to let you view a webcam connected elsewhere by URL or IP.